# Flink FileSource, File Relocation, and Job Progress Tracking

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am utilizing Flink's FileSource to continuously read files from a directory.I'm inquiring whether there exists a method to automatically relocate processed files from a directory once a Flink job has completed processing them. I'm particularly keen on understanding how this particular use case is currently managed in production environments. Additionally, I'm curious about whether there's a way to track which files in the directory have been processed by the Flink job.Is there any java code available for this use case ?